# Consider a first order quasi linear equation under various Cauchy Data

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the first order Quasi linear PDE given by $$uu_x+u_y=1$$

As usual

$$J=\begin{vmatrix}
f'(s_o)  & a(f(s_0),g(s_0),h(s_0))\\
g'(s_o)  & b(f(s_0),g(s_0),h(s_0))
\end{vmatrix}$$ 
The characteristic equations associated here are:

$ \dfrac{dx}{dt}=u,\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1,\dfrac{du}{dt}=1$

Solve the Cauchy Problem associated with the following data:

a) $x=s,y=s,z=\dfrac{s}{2}, 0 \le s \le 1$

Here $$J=\begin{vmatrix}
1  & \dfrac{s}{2}\\
1  & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

For $J=0$, $s=2$ which can't happen and so solution exists.

So solving the equations along the Cauchy data , we get $$u=t+\dfrac{s}{2},y=t+s,x=\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{st}{2}+s$$
$y-u=\dfrac{s}{2},t=2u-y,x=\dfrac{1}{2}t(y)+2y-2u=y(u-\dfrac{y}{2})+2y-2u$

Solving which I get $$u=\frac{x-2y+\frac{y^2}{2}}{y-2}$$

The only place where problem can happen is where $y=2$ and I think it can't happen because $s$ is bounded by $1$.

b) $x=\frac{s^2}{2},y=s,z=s, 0 \le s \le 1$

Here $$J=\begin{vmatrix}
s  & s\\
1  & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ 
Having known this I look at if $$\frac{f'}{a}=\frac{g'}{b}=\frac{h'}{c}$$ is satisfied or not and they turn out to be equal.

So I set out to find the characteristics and $$x=\frac{t^2}{2}+st+\frac{s^2}{2},y=t+s,u=t+s$$ and as it turns out there are two solutions to this one. One is $u=y$ and the other one is  $u=\sqrt{2x}$

(c) $x=s^2,y=2s,z=s, 0 \le s \le 1$

The question here says that this particular data admits no solution to the Cauchy data. So I set out to find the solution expecting a problem somewhere. The Jacobian turned out to be $0$. The characteristic equations came out to be $$u=t+s,y=t+2s,x=\frac{t^2}{2}+st+s^2$$

Solving all these three equations yielded $$x=\frac{2u^2-2uy+y^2}{2}$$

This is a quadratic equation in $u$ and upon solving , I arrived at $$u=\frac{y+\sqrt{4x-y^2}}{2}$$
Ofcourse this is welldefined for $4x \ge y^2$ , which I believe is true from the given initial conditions. I even checked out that this satisfies the given differential equation.

d) In the fourth bit , the question asks to check the conditions in (c) just with the domain $0 \le s\le 3$ and says the Jacobian vanishes only on a subset.I am a bit perplexed here. The jacobian in my calculation should have to  be   $$J=\begin{vmatrix}
2s  & s\\
2  & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Thanks for the help!!